# Problems with Tomcat Installation os OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, linux, apache, bash, tomcat

Problems with Tomcat Installation os OS X Mavericks

I cannot start the server, because it does not start:

```
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/catalina.sh: line 399: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory

SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ /opt/apache-tomcat-8*/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/catalina.sh: line 399: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
-bash: /bin/startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

Apache Tomcat Installation:

1. tutorialforlinux.com/2014/01/10/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-mac-10-9-mavericks-os-x-easy-visual-guide/

   ```
   SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ sudo mkdir /opt
   Password:
   mkdir: /opt: File exists
   SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ sudo mv /Users/stefanieness/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8* /opt/
   SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ /opt/apache-tomcat-8*/bin/startup.sh
   Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12
   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12
   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/temp
   Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
   Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
   touch: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/catalina.sh: line 399: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
   ```
2. tutorialforlinux.com/2014/01/09/how-to-install-oracle-jdk-7-on-mac-10-9-mavericks-easy-guide/

Followed the tutorial.

```
SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

3. ERROR:

```
sudo mv /Users/stefanieness/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8* /opt/
mv: rename /Users/stefanieness/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.12 to /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12: Directory not empty
```

4. Followed tutorial: wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/java-tomcat-resteasy/

```
SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ sudo mkdir /opt
Password:
mkdir: /opt: File exists
SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ sudo mv /Users/<myUser>/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8* /opt/
-bash: myUser: No such file or directory
SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ sudo mv /Users/stefanieness/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8* /opt/
mv: rename /Users/stefanieness/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.12 to /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12: Directory not empty
SEICCN-3:assignment1 stefanieness$ cd ~/Downloads/
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ tar -zxvf ./apache-tomcat-8.0.12.tar.gz
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open './apache-tomcat-8.0.12.tar.gz'
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local
Password:
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8* /usr/local
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ sudo rm -f /Library/Tomcat
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8* /Library/Tomcat
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ sudo chown -R stefanieness/Library/Tomcat
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ sudo chmod +x /Library/Tomcat/bin/*.sh
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$ /opt/apache-tomcat-8*/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/catalina.sh: line 399: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs/catalina.out: No such file or directory
SEICCN-3:Downloads stefanieness$  cd /Users/stefanieness/tomcat/bin
-bash: cd: /Users/stefanieness/tomcat/bin: No such file or directory

Other tutorials that I found:
editrocket.com/articles/tomcat_mac.html
Starting the server this way does not work.
```

Does somebody know a good tutorial or what can I do?

Comment: At least some of those you got errors because you already had a directory in place. You can't ignore basic shell/OS/filesystem fundamentals.

Comment: And what can I do to install it?

Comment: edit .bash_profile file and in that export the CATALINA_HOME with correct path...

Comment: Define "install it". Uncompressing it to a directory somewhere under your home directory and running it from there works fine, and you don't have to set anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing at least two things. First, create the log directory (the `-p` creates every directory in the path and doesn't complain if they exist):

```
mkdir -p /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/logs
```

Also, to @wrongAnswer's point, you need either run on the command line before you start tomcat or put in a profile or rc script:

```
env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12 /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/catalina.sh jpda start
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I never had to set CATALINA_HOME.